# How to extract the Subtotal Price using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using Xpath and having trouble pulling out information I need.

It is basically a Price - Subtotal. The HTML Image is attached, and the xpath code I am using is below. What am I missing? At the end I am looking to get the price value into a string.

```
w = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order-summary"]/section/section[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/span')
print(w.text())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the Price - Subtotal text i.e. *$27.99* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.total-line__price > span.order-summary__emphasis").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@class='total-line__price']/span[contains(@class, 'order-summary__emphasis')]").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*`visibility_of_element_located()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "std.total-line__price > span.order-summary__emphasis"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='total-line__price']/span[contains(@class, 'order-summary__emphasis')]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)